# Make app think Windows is not in Safe Mode?

Tags: windows, safe-mode

Some applications check whether Windows is booted in safe mode in order to restrict their features.

Is there a way to hide the fact that Windows is in safe mode (registry edit maybe)?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a practical idea.

It may well be possible to fool an application into thinking it is not in Safe Mode. I have no idea how. But that isn't the issue. Safe Mode is a special mode designed for diagnostic and repair purposes when a normal boot is not possible. To accomplish this only a limited set of essential services and drivers are loaded at bootup. This imposes some limitations on functionality. Applications don't just make arbitrary decisions regarding which features they will provide in this Safe Mode. This decision is made based on which features can actually operate. If a specific feature will not work in a specific situation it is normal practice to not allow it. This is better than attempting an operation only to have it fail.

You may mislead an application about the environment in which it is running but you cannot escape the consequences of doing so.

Comment: +1.  Safe Mode alters the environment in so many ways, that there are numerous ways that a program could check for this.  Therefore, there isn't a single way that would entirely do this.  If I were trying to make a program that checks for safe mode, I would see if Google (maybe especially MSDN) provided a simple method, like an API call.  Maybe there's a standard way I don't know of.  Otherwise, I may want to check if a boot log said what mode was used.  But other applications might take different approaches, like looking for a lack of common drivers used with physical equipment.